# Javascript: Value cannot pass through a condition although it is true

Tags: javascript, webkitspeechrecognition

When I'm doing some stuff, I figure out a weird problem.
I try to make a voice recognition. The first part of the condition works correctly but it does not work for the second part.

```
var v;

function test() {
  var ses = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
  ses.lang = "En"
  ses.continuous = true;
  ses.start();
  ses.onresult = function(event)
    if (event.results.length > 0) {
      sonuc = event.results[event.results.length - 1];
      document.querySelector("input").value = sonuc[0].transcript;
      v = sonuc[0].transcript;
      console.log(v + " 1");

      if (v == "good") {
        switchLED('on');
        console.log(v + "2");
        console.log("OK !");
        console.log("LED ok");
      }

      if (v == "bad") {
        switchLED('off');
        console.log(v + "2");
        console.log("OK !");
        console.log("LED off");
      }
    }
  }
```

For the first time, I said: `good`
and the results were:

```
good 1 
good 2
OK ! 
LED OK
```

This was correct.

Then, for the second time if I say: `bad`
the result is:

```
bad 1
```

and it did not go through the condition `if(v == "bad")`.

It is only happened when `bad` is the second word I said. If I refresh the page and said "bad" directly on the first time, I will get all the correct results.

Comment: when you are checking for exakt match you have to be 100% sure. as it may containe space or otherwise

Comment: Did you debug the code step by step to see what's going on? You might be missing something there. It just doesn't make sense to me that `console.log(v + ' 1')` prints the correct transcription but then fails in the latter condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Mozzila's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognitionAlternative/transcript):

> For continuous recognition, **leading or trailing whitespace will be included where necessary** so that concatenation of consecutive SpeechRecognitionResults produces a proper transcript of the session.

This matches *exactly* what you described. Since your speech recognition session is continuous (as seen in `ses.continuous = true`) what happens is that when you say any word for the first time, the transcriptor will get the word correctly. But when it recognises the next word, a leading whitespace will be added. You probably miscopied your console output, which must've been like this:

```
good 1 
good 2
OK ! 
LED OK

 bad 1 
^ leading space here
```

Indeed, `" bad"` is not equal to `"bad"`. This is why the string didn't pass the condition. To solve this, just make sure to [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) your string:

```
var v;

function test() {
  var ses = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
  ses.lang = "En"
  ses.continuous = true;
  ses.start();
  ses.onresult = function(event)
    if (event.results.length > 0) {
      sonuc = event.results[event.results.length - 1];
      document.querySelector("input").value = sonuc[0].transcript;
      v = sonuc[0].transcript.trim(); // <-- trim here
      console.log(v + " 1");

      if (v == "good") {
        switchLED('on');
        console.log(v + "2");
        console.log("OK !");
        console.log("LED ok");
      }

      if (v == "bad") {
        switchLED('off');
        console.log(v + "2");
        console.log("OK !");
        console.log("LED off");
      }
    }
  }
```

Then your code should work as expected. Hope it helps!